# In Mongo, how do I find all the documents, but display only their titles?

Tags: mongodb, database

There's a ['title'] attribute inside each document.
How can I do a .find, but only display the title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can retrieve a subset of fields within the documents as follows:

e.g. looking retrieving only the title field for books with a given ISBN:

```
db.Books.find({ISBN : "1234567890" }, { title : 1 } );
```

You can also do field negation, i.e. return all fields EXCEPT the ones you specify. There's a good reference on this on [MongoDB.org](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields)

Answer (score 0):

you can find that info at http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields